# ADO.NET data access layer

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ado.net

I'm maintaining an existing C# application which uses classic ADO.NET as a data access technology.The existing code creates a new instance of the `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects **EVERY** single time some interaction with the database is required. To make things simpler I wrote a little class to simplify this process to prevemt code repetition but I'm not an expert at ADO.NET so I wanted to ask if you can review my code and let me know if I missed any ADO.NET best practices or if the code below may impact DB operations negatively in anyway:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace MyApp.DataAccess
{
    public class DataAccessLayer : IDisposable
    {
        private SqlConnection _connection = new SqlConnection();
        private SqlCommand _command = new SqlCommand();

        public string ConnectionString 
        {
            get { return DBConfig.ConnectionString; }
        }

        public SqlCommand Command 
        {
            get { return _command; }
            set { _command = value; }
        }

        public SqlConnection SQLConnection 
        {
            get
            {
                if(_connection == null || _connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    _connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
                    _connection.Open();
                }
                return _connection;
            }
        }

        public void SetCommand(string commandText,CommandType commandType)
        {
            _command = new SqlCommand(commandText, SQLConnection);
            _command.CommandType = commandType;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_connection != null)
                _connection.Dispose();

            if (_command != null)
                _command.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This class prevents you from using the `using`-statement which is recommended always. It encapsulates objects that implement `IDisposable` and should be disposed as soon as possible. That also closes the connection. People using your class will forget that.

Comment: But that's why I inherit IDisposable and use the Dispose method to close the connection.Or is that not the same thing?

Comment: Well, actually yes. But i don't think much of classes like this anyway. It encourages people to reuse it instead of always dispose it when they are  finished. They will create one `DataAccessLayer` instance per form or app, maybe even `static` and reuse it everytime.

Comment: Also be aware that by default ADO.NET uses connection pooling: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx, so code that constantly opens/closes connections on each use is rarely a performance issue.

Comment: I think you are trying to abstract at a too granular level. Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573054/whats-the-most-dry-appropriate-way-to-execute-an-sql-command) for ideas on higher level abstractions that still use the `Connection` object and SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim explained, I would rather code this with the [using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/yh598w02.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) statement. This will automatically close and dispose your `SqlConnection` instance.

Take a look at this example here from the MSDN page about the [SqlConnection class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        // Do work here; connection closed on following line.
    }
```

And what model_dialog explained, is also correct.
If you invoke the `Open` method on the `SqlConnection` class  the framework will not necesserily really open a new connection.

Instead it will check whether there is already an appropiate connection available in the connection pool. It does this by checking the connection string. If it founds a suitable connection, the connection pool will just return this connection with almost no performance impact. The connection pool is a catching component for SqlConnections so to speak.

See here for more details: [SQL Server Connection Pooling (ADO.NET)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: But if I go this route I'm back at square one where I have a ton of repeatable code and that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid.I'm using one connection object and I have written the code to dispose of the connection and command when the garbage collector runs, until then it will use the same instance so in theory sounds good, all I need is an expert in the field to confirm whether there is no fundamental flaw in my data access logic